# Change Model Values using JQuery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the model data with jquery. I make 2 hiddenfor elements and change their value inide the jquery (i chekch their values using alert and all seems to be working) but when i use ajax to call function the values are default (nothing). Is this the wrong sollution?

This is my view code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(x) x.ElementNameSelected, New With {.id = "ElementSelected"})
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(x) x.Remove, New With {.id = "Remove"})
```

this is my JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.RemoveNode').click(function () {
    if ($(".event_result").html() == "")
        alert("Nie Wyprales elementu z drzewa!")
    else {
        $("#ElementSelected").val($(".event_result").html());
        $("#Remove").val(true);

        alert($("#ElementSelected").val());
        alert($("#Remove").val());

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/TreeTest/AddNewTree",
            data: '@Model'
        });        
    }
});
</script>
```

setting the model values would look something like that?

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/TreeTest/AddNewTree",
            data: {
                '@Model' : {
                    Remove: true,
                    NameToAdd : "wololo"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: .event_result is div ? or textfield ?

Comment: Well, the problem is that you see this as two-way-binding. When you set `data: '@Model'` you are actually setting the value of the model before it left the server, i.e. before it was changed by your jQuery interaction. This is not Angular, I'm afraid. What you need to do here is to get all the values from your form and pass each of them using the `data` property of the `$.ajax` function.

Comment: @LittleDragon.event_result is div in which i have some important text value

Comment: could you check the updated question and tell me is this the proper way to set values in ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it the easiest way possible (well i think :P )
I made

```
Html.BeginForm
```

and i have added

```
"onclick='submitRemove()'
```

inside thesubmit and in jQuery function submitRemove i set values for hiddenfor :)

Thanks for all help!